# Swift PJ-SIP Integration: Issue Displaying Video Stream in UIView

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, video-streaming, pjsip

I'm working on a Swift-based VoIP application using PJ-SIP and facing an issue with displaying the video stream in a UIView. I've set up PJSIPManager to handle SIP functionalities, and I'm trying to embed the video stream within a UIView in my UIViewController. However, the video is not being displayed as expected.

Code Setup:
In my PJSIPManager, I have the following configuration:

```swift
struct PJSIPManager {
    private init() {
        var cfg = pjsua_config()
        pjsua_config_default(&cfg)
        cfg.cb.on_call_media_state = on_call_media_state
    }

    var vid_win: UIView? = nil

    private func on_call_media_state(pjsipID: pjsua_call_id) {
        // ... [media state handling code] ...
        if (media[Int(mi)].type == PJMEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO) {
            PJSIPManager.instance?.isVideoCall = true
            let wid = media[Int(mi)].stream.vid.win_in;
            var wi = pjsua_vid_win_info();
            if (pjsua_vid_win_get_info(wid, &wi) == PJ_SUCCESS.rawValue) {
                PJSIPManager.instance?.vid_win = Unmanaged<UIView>.fromOpaque(wi.hwnd.info.ios.window).takeUnretainedValue();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my UIViewController, I'm doing the following:

```swift
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
         DispatchQueue.main.async {
            if let isVideoCall = PJSIPManager.getInstance()?.isVideoCall ,isVideoCall{
                if PJSIPManager.getInstance()?.vid_win != nil {
                    self.view.addSubview(PJSIPManager.getInstance()!.vid_win!)
                }
                PJSIPManager.getInstance()!.vid_win!.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
                PJSIPManager.getInstance()!.vid_win!.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
                PJSIPManager.instance?.vid_win?.isHidden = false
                PJSIPManager.getInstance()!.vid_win!.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                    PJSIPManager.getInstance()!.vid_win!.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo:self.view.centerXAnchor),
                    PJSIPManager.getInstance()!.vid_win!.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
                    PJSIPManager.getInstance()!.vid_win!.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100),
                    PJSIPManager.getInstance()!.vid_win!.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100)
                ])
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

With this setup, I'm not able to see the video stream.

Issue:

When I use the vid_win directly from PJSIPManager, the video doesn't play.but If I set a background color to the view, I can see the view with the background color when the call is a video call, indicating that the view is added to the view hierarchy, but it's not rendering the video stream.

How can I ensure that vid_win is correctly receiving and displaying the video stream?
Are there any specific considerations in PJ-SIP for embedding video in a UIView?

I made sure that isVideoCall is true and that PJSIPManager.getInstance()?.vid_win is not nil

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that i called

```swift
acc_cfg.vid_out_auto_transmit = pj_bool_t(PJ_TRUE.rawValue)
acc_cfg.vid_in_auto_show = pj_bool_t(PJ_TRUE.rawValue)
```

before

```swift
pjsua_acc_config_default(&acc_cfg);
```

instead of the opposite